# Integrate omniture in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, adobe-analytics

I am integrating the "Omniture" in WP7 app. As i know [WCf service](https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/blog/getting-started-with-the-omniture-apis-using-visual-studio-2010-wcf)  is available for the  ominiture api in c#. Is there any seperate WCf service for Wp7. Is it possiible integrate the 
omniture in Wp7?. Please mention the any app using the omniture.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you need to explain it a bit more. Have you tried using the WCF as shown in their example? Can you show that code and explain what didn't work?

Comment: @ keyboardP: The code will work in the C# Desktop application but i am not able add the associated dlls in the WP7 project. it will give while adding error as not compatible dlls.

Comment: You mean the `Omniture` DLLs are incompatible? Then where does WCF come into this question? The point of WCF is to abstract the workings of the 'server' side. Therefore, WP7 is capable of using WCF to interact with a remote WCF service. However, you seem to want to add the `Omniture` DLLs? If so, then you'll get a better response on the Omniture forums regarding WP7 support.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented Omniture integration with a Windows Phone 7 app (sorry can't say which one).

There are libraries from Omniture which handle calling the web service for you. You just need to worry about passing the right information to their criptically named properties and parameters.

Contact Omniture to get the right assemblies.

Comment: There is an omniture debugger that can save you some time when debugging your omniture setup: http://omniture.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/534

Comment: @potench that debugger only appears to work in browser, not from a client app. We used Fiddler to monitor what was sent